# How to add ']' to end of Json

Tags: blazor

Can anyone show me an example of how I can include ']' bracket or remove ',' at end of my json file.

1. My json files are missing closing bracket ']' at the end.
2. There are few files which has ',' at the end instead of ']' bracket. So ',' need to be removed.

Since most of my files are not in proper json format, they go to catch. How do I now open and append ']' at the end of json file or remove ',' (which is at end of file).

```
    var utf8Json = _loadedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10); 

    try
    {
        var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(utf8Json);
        json = jsonDocument;
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        @*Now, here how do I go about adding ']' or removing ',' at the end of json *@
    }
```

Edited:

I get "System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ']' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0" on the last line of catch -> JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText + ']').

var utf8Json = _loadedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10);

```
    try
    {
        var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(utf8Json);
        json = jsonDocument;
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        using var reader = new StreamReader(utf8Json);
        string jsonText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        @* if (jsonText[jsonText.Length - 1] == ',')
        //if (jsonText.Substring(jsonText.Length - 1) == ',')
        {
        jsonText = jsonText.Substring(0, jsonText.Length - 1);
        }*@
        else
        {
        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText + ']'); // I get error in this line
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, below 10MB and has [ bracket included. Says "Expected depth to be zero at the end of the JSON payload. There is an open JSON object or array that should be closed. LineNumber: 1975 | BytePositionInLine: 0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the catch you are too late.

How about

```
var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(utf8Json + ']');
```

#### Update

Ok, you have a Stream. You need to get a string to fix it, and it seems better to remove the trailing `,` first.

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(utf8Json);
string jsonText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
jsonText = jsonText.substring(0, jsonText.Length-1); 
var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText); // and maybe:  + ']';
```

Comment: Says '+' cannot be applied to operands of type stream and char

Comment: I have edited my question for exact scenario. I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I get ']' is an invalid start of a value on the last line JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText + ']'). I have added code under edited.

Comment: Sorry all these time, I had been trying my code inside catch. Thanks a lot for the answer.